# Mono Program Crashes on OSX Lion

Tags: c#, mono, osx-lion, monodevelop, osx-mountain-lion

As a deployment test, I created a bare-bones C# Mono project in MonoDevelop. It only shows a window. I didn't make any changes to the code after creation.
It installs and runs perfectly fine on Mountain Lion.

When I install and run it on Lion, however, I get the following error:

> Process:         launchd [329] Path:
>   /Applications/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/Test Identifier:
>   com.yourcompany.test Version:         ??? (???) Code Type:       X86
>   (Native) Parent Process:  launchd [281]
>
> Date/Time:       2013-06-06 16:00:51.919 -0700 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.7.5 (11G63) Report Version:  9
>
> Interval Since Last Report:          124001 sec Crashes Since Last
>   Report:           28 Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   28 Anonymous
>   UUID:                      1AB061C0-779D-43EC-B6D3-E8C6AED2969C
>
> Crashed Thread:  Unknown
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000008fe01030
>
> Backtrace not available
>
> Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):   eax:
>   0x00000000  ebx: 0x00000000  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x00000000   edi:
>   0x00000000  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0x00000000  esp: 0x00000000    ss:
>   0x00000023  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x8fe01030   cs: 0x0000001b    ds:
>   0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000000   cr2:
>   0x8fe01030 Logical CPU: 2
>
> Binary images description not available
>
> External Modification Summary:   Calls made by other processes
>   targeting this process:
>       task_for_pid: 1
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by this process:
>       task_for_pid: 0
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by all processes on this machine:
>       task_for_pid: 113
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0
>
> Model: iMac12,1, BootROM IM121.0047.B1E, 4 processors, Intel Core i7,
>   2.8 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.71f22 Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M, AMD Radeon HD 6770M, PCIe, 512 MB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333
>   MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D48392020 Memory Module:
>   BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD,
>   0x484D54333531533642465238432D48392020 AirPort:
>   spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x9A), Atheros
>   9380: 4.0.67.5-P2P Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 18 devices,
>   1 incoming serial ports Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
>   Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1 Serial ATA Device: ST31000528AS,
>   1 TB Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-STDVDRW  GA32N USB Device: FaceTime HD
>   Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x850b, 0xfa200000 / 3 USB Device:
>   hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2 USB Device: Dell
>   USB Mouse, 0x413c  (Dell Inc.), 0x3200, 0xfa120000 / 5 USB Device:
>   BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4 USB
>   Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8215,
>   0xfa111000 / 7 USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514,
>   0xfd100000 / 2 USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242,
>   0xfd120000 / 4 USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader,
>   apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfd110000 / 3

Any thoughts? As mentioned, everything works fine on Mountain Lion.
I've tested multiple Mountain Lion computers (works fine) and multiple Lion computers (all fail).

Thanks very much

Comment: Can you run any other mono programs? (try just running the C# shell or something)

Comment: Yes, I can actually. Oddly enough, the program crashes before it can even prompt it to install the Mono Framework. That's the first thing it does when it's run successfully on Mountain Lion.

Comment: Oh, you didn't say that you hadn't installed it. You can't execute Mono programs without the Mono framework, and they won't ask you to install the framework when they run. There is an option somewhere in Mono to include the framework into the executable. There's also a way to compile it AOT instead of JIT.

Comment: I installed the Mono Framework and still get the same result unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, I'd probably just try building it on Lion, like Rolf Bjane Kving said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a problem of where you built it: try building it in Lion instead to see if that makes a difference. I've seen problems before when trying to execute a program on an older OS than where it was built.

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll set this up and check the results and let you know.

Comment: You were right, needed to be compiled on Lion. Thanks very much